# Accessing Elements in a nested list in python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, multidimensional-array, nested-loops, data-analysis

I am a newbie in python and I have data in a nested list in this format. I want to do something if the value of age in the dictionaries are equal.

```
[
  [
      {
       "name":"AAAAA",
       "age":"12",
      "class":"box"
      }
  ],
  [
      {
      "name":"DDDD",
      "age":"10",
      "class":"space"
      }
  ],
  [
      {"name":"BBBB"},
      {"age":"16"},
      {"class":"cage"}
  ],
  [
      {
      "name":"EEEE",
      "age":"20",
      "class":"sage"
      }
  ],

]
```

Comment: Are you familiar with pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/ ? It is the go-to library for data wrangling in python (besides numpy)

Comment: If the value of age in the dictionaries are equal *to what*?

Comment: Did you try to write some code that does what you want? What was the problem?

Comment: yes, i did. this isnth the original code, I am fetching the data from an API. this is just the structure of the data coming back. I received typeError problems trying to access the elements in the loop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The main idea is to store all the ages in a list, get list of duplicate ages and access the dictionary using that list

```
age_list = [] 

for l in dict_list:
    temp_dict = l[0]
    age_list.append(temp_dict["age"])

# get set of duplicates in age list
dup_ages = set([x for x in l if l.count(x) > 1])

for index, age in enumerate(age_list):
    for dup_age in dup_ages:            # do something for a given duplicate age
        if dup_age == age:
            dict_list[index]            # do something in the dict
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. i understand this logic, and besides, I would love to ask what that set method you used in dup_ages mean
however, I am getting this error message from the above code
age_list.append(temp_dict["age"])
KeyError: 'age'
Thanks

Comment: And besides, the l[0] is {"name":"AAAA"}

Comment: @D.B.J for dup_age we are traversing through the list of ages, counting the number of occurrences and storing as a list that number if it occurs more than once. Then we set that list as numbers that appeared more than twice will be duplicated in that list

Comment: @D.B.J theres a key error because i think the data isn't what u posted. l[0] should hold: {
       "name":"AAAAA",
       "age":"12",
      "class":"box"
      }  which has age in it.